# Creating Custom Font Awesome based Image component in .net maui

Tags: xaml, maui

I'm trying to create a custom image control in dotnet maui that will display any given font awesome icon registered in my global resources. The idea is that the control has a string icon name, and then uses a converter to pull out that FontImageSource from the global resources. For the life of me I can't get this to work, no icon is ever displayed (though i can hardcode using static resource easily).

I've registered a FontImageSource in my app resources:

```
    <FontImage x:Key="SettingsIcon" FontFamily="FontAwesome" Glyph="&#xf013;" Size="22" Color="Black" />
```

My IconImage class is:

```
public partial class IconImage : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty IconNameProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IconName), typeof(string), typeof(IconImage));
    
    public string IconName
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(IconNameProperty);
        set => SetValue(IconNameProperty, value);
    }
    
    public IconImage()
    {
        BindingContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

with the xaml being:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Example.Views.IconImage"
             >
    <ContentView.Content>
        <Image Source="{Binding IconName, Converter={StaticResource StringToIconConverter}}" />
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

The referenced converter pulls out the given FontImage using the passed in name.

So here are the issues:

1. I can only get the icon to show if i simply hard code it and replace the <Image> with:

`<Image Source="{StaticResource SettingsIcon}" />`

2. If I initialise the icon name in the code behind in the constructor then i can at least get the converter to trigger and it seems to find the FontImageSource, but no icon is displayed.
3. If i try to use the IconImage without any hard coding, then i can't get anything to trigger (even setting the property). I suspect, therefore, that I haven't set up the property or the binding properly. Example (from inside a data template and using MauiCommunity markup style):
      `new IconImage().Bind(IconImage.IconNameProperty, nameof(Caption.IconName)).Size(24,24),`

Any help appreciated!

Comment: where is the definintion of `StringToIconConverter` ? are you sure the issue is not inside that converter ?

Comment: Thank you for responding. The converter was fine. The problem turned out to be this:

        BindingContext = this;

Setting the bindingcontext from the constructor in this way just didn't work. Instead i left it out and was able to do:

<ContentView ...
             x:Name="Self">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <Image Source="{Binding IconName, Source={x:Reference Self}, Converter={StaticResource StringToIconConverter}}" />
    ...
</ContentView>

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that may better help me find your problem?